# Determining brushed DC motor inertia for modeling a motor

Tags: motors

I'm making an model of a DC motor, and following the guide for [measuring motor parameters](http://support.ctc-control.com/customer/elearning/younkin/motorParameters.pdf):

I am having trouble measuring the motor's inertia, as the guide for this section is vague. This is a graph of my RPM over time (in milliseconds):

[image: RPM vs Milliseconds]

I know the graph is noisy, but its the best I can capture at the moment.
What I can't figure out is, to find the acceleration, what section of this graph is the linear region the guide refers to? It states

> The acceleration is therefore
>   the change in velocity for the linear part of the exponential curve divided by the time
>   elapsed for the detected rate of change in velocity

Another document, states this when saying how to measure motor inertia:

> The rotor inertia can be estimated from measurements of the mechanical time constant, kt
>   ,
>   and R. Alternatively, a constant current could be applied to the motor and the motor’s position differentiated
>   twice to get acceleration α. Then the inertia can be estimated using the relation J = T /α = ktI/α. Note
>   that constant current/torque/acceleration is not possible for long periods of time.
>   (from [Mystery Motor Data Sheet](http://hades.mech.northwestern.edu/images/6/61/Asst7.pdf))

This implies there is another way to measure inertia using kt and R (which I know both of), but doesn't seem to state it. I would love to know what it is.